# Cyclic reference error in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Good day,

I am getting an error saying: 'The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference'.

Parent pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.solveit.cmr</groupId>
    <artifactId>cmr-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>cmr-parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>cmr-core</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solveit.cmr.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>cmr-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

child pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>cmr-core</artifactId>
<name>cmr-core</name>
<groupId>com.solveit.cmr.core</groupId>


<parent>
    <groupId>com.solveit.cmr</groupId>
    <artifactId>cmr-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Split up into multiple modules, don't try to make a parent depend on one of its modules. Parents build 'first'.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? Remove the dependency in the parent.

Comment: I thought the parent pom depends on all of its child-modules, that's why I have created this dependency. I am new to Maven so thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The `<modules>` section tell maven the hierarchy between the parent pom and childs pom.

The parent should contain all the common section to all the modules.

 such as `<dependencyManagement>`, `<plugins>` and `<properties>`